# Different representation of line

Tags: prolog

I am learning the Prolog. I tried to write

```
 Anew is + (A is H1 * H2),
```

instead of

```
is(Anew,+(A,*(H1,H2))),
```

but it produces an error. Where is my mistake? Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same:

```
Anew is + (A is H1 * H2),
%       ^^   ^^  bad!
```

instead, write (given standard operators):

```
Anew is A + H1 * H2,
```